# Loop is not working

Tags: java

this code is to be used to write the data inserted in to a file 
when the loop runs the second student dont get entered i dont know why 
this keeps getting stuck at the second student and i have been working on this for hours

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class wonder
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

    FileWriter ww = new FileWriter("D:\\student details.txt");
    BufferedWriter o = new BufferedWriter(ww);

    int counter = 0 ;
    int stnum = 1;

    while(counter < 4)
    {
        String name = "";
        int marks = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter student " + stnum + " name : " );
        name = c.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter marks : ");
        marks = c.nextInt();

        ww.write(stnum + " " + name + " " + marks );
        ww.close();

        counter++;
        stnum++;

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you create a BufferedWriter but never use it?

Comment: put ww.close()outside the loop

Answer (score 3):

You close your FileWriter in each iteration of your while loop... what did you *think* would happen?

Answer (score 1):

you close the writer in the loop, move the close statement outside of the loop

```
ww.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to do

put **ww.close();** outside the while loop
change **c.nextLine()**; to **c.next();**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class wonder
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileWriter ww = new FileWriter("D:\\student details.txt");
    BufferedWriter o = new BufferedWriter(ww);
    int counter = 0 ;
    int stnum = 1;
    while(counter < 4)
    {

        String name = "";
        int marks = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter student " + stnum + " name : " );
        name = c.next();

        System.out.print("Enter marks : ");
        marks = c.nextInt();

        ww.write(stnum + " " + name + " " + marks );

        counter++;
        stnum++;

    }
  ww.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you advising to put the scanner declaration **inside** the loop?

Comment: okay...no need of putting the scanner inside loop.....instead make change nextLine to next().........see my update